# ReactDataGrid not displaying rows correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-data-grid version ^4.0.9 and the row data does not appear for me even though it appears the expected data is in the grid.

Outside of my component definition I define:

```
const colsTest = [{key: "test1", name: "Test 1", filterable: true}, {key: "test2", name: "Test 2", filterable: true}, {key: "test3", name: "Test 3", filterable: true}];
const rowsTest = [{test1: "Test", test2: "Test", test3: "Test"}];
```

and then in the render function of my component, I return:

```
<ReactDataGrid 
   columns={colsTest}
   rowGetter={i => rowsTest[i]}
   rowCount={rowsTest.length}
   minHeight={750}
/>
```

I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2TMs.png) to verify that Chrome's inspect shows that the data grid contains the expected data, and another [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nc8k.png) to show what is rendered.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Obviously, I have used dummy data for sharing purposes but with the actual data, the output is the same.

Comment: Update: the issue appears to be because the component is used within a tab component meaning the component is hidden until the relevant tab is clicked on. I noted another issue (https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/85) that sounded similar to my problem, but the last comments claims there was a fix issued in 2016, I tried updating my version and the problem persists. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, make sure each outer div has style height set to 100%.